# Flink short jobs do not export prometheus job_name field

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-batch

**[DESCRIPTION]**

I am running Flink 1.11.1 on Kubernetes, and set up monitoring stack using Prometheus and Grafana.

I have observed running WordCount example on Flink Cluster (submitted via UI) does not return `$(job_name)` on prometheus.

To troubleshoot, I have downloaded flink sample WordCount jobs and forced them to run longer using `Thread.sleep()`. As seen in the below screenshot, I ran the job, then the longer version.

[shorter and longer running screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UpDvc.png)

Only second run (longer jobs) export `$(job_name)` field on prometheus as seen below on Grafana dashboard screenshot (`label_values(job_name)`). That hints that shorter running jobs does not export given field.

[job name field on Grafana dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NITRT.png)

I have also tried to run pushgateway exporter with Flink's suggested settings which resulted in same result as above.

**[QUESTION]**

Is there a way to collect job_name metric from short running jobs, is my setup wrong? Or is it impossible to achieve it due to scrape interval on prometheus? Thank you.